# How to use cproto on windows

Tags: c++, c

I have few lengthy C and CPP code files and want to get function names in them.

I downloaded [`cproto-4.7c-bin.zip`](http://invisible-island.net/cproto/cproto.html) to my Windows 7 system and tried the following in the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\cproto-4.7c-bin\bin>cproto -f fileExec.c
/* stdin */
```

Nothing happened. It appears to hang; it displays `/* stdin */` until I close the command prompt window (effectively killing it).  The `trace.out` file in `C:\Users\admin\Desktop\cproto-4.7c-bin\bin` is blank.

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is on hold ... it's pretty clear to me what is being asked and I've answered the question.  What exactly would one of the folks who put this on hold like to see improved in the way the question is asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/* stdin */` message is saying that it's waiting for input on stdin.

At first, I found the original, but now defunct project [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cproto/).  It looks like the newer version, that is referenced in the question, has decent documentation. If you execute `cproto --help` it prints out the following usage statement:

```
cproto: invalid option -- '-'
usage: cproto [ option ... ] [ file ... ]
Options:
  -a, -t           Convert function definitions to ANSI or traditional style
  -b               Rewrite function definitions in both styles
  -c               Enable comments in prototype parameters
  -e               Output "extern" keyword before global declarations
  -f n             Set function prototype style (0 to 3)
  -l               Generate output in lint-library style
  -o file          Redirect output to file
  -O file          Redirect errors to file
  -p               Disable formal parameter promotion
  -q               Disable include file read failure messages
  -s               Output static declarations also
  -S               Output static declarations only
  -T               Output type definitions
  -v               Output variable declarations
  -x               Output variables and functions declared "extern"
  -m               Put macro around prototype parameters
  -M name          Set name of prototype macro
  -d               Omit prototype macro definition
  -P template      Set prototype format template " int f (a, b)"
  -F template      Set function definition format template " int f (a, b)"
  -C template      Set format for function definition with parameter comments
  -D name[=value]  Define C preprocessor symbol
  -U name          Undefine C preprocessor symbol
  -I directory     Add #include search directory
  -E command       Run specified C preprocessor command
  -E 0             Do not run any C preprocessor
  -V               Print version information
```

You need to provide an extra argument to the `-f` option (or simply remove it).  For example:
**C:\Users\admin\Desktop\cproto-4.7c-bin\bin>cproto -f3 fileExec.c**
or
**C:\Users\admin\Desktop\cproto-4.7c-bin\bin>cproto fileExec.c**

Comment: Hi rkersh, i tried with above options. 
Now getting error : 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Im searching for this new issue .. please let me know if you know way out.

Comment: What is the exact command you are running and what is the exact output?  It sounds like you're trying to compile something....

Comment: actually im new in c,c++ and got assigned to this project where we need to get function/method declared/implemented in each .c, .cpp files so as to rename / replace them.
i dont know why gcc is required for cproto on windows? 
Command im running : C:\Users\admin\Desktop\cproto-4.7c-bin\bin>cproto -f fileExec.c